# Is there an existing machine-readable enumeration/list/taxonomy of sports/games?

Tags: standards, taxonomy

I'm looking for a machine-readable enumeration/list of sports, ideally categorized in some form. This [1] is the closest I could find online, but it isn't machine readable (and contains ambiguity too, e.g. one sport matches to more than one category).

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sports

Comment: In the time it takes for you to look for such a list, you could probably word process that wikipedia article into what you want... In fact, I just pasted a section into notepad, and that strips out all the formatting without any additional work.

Comment: That's certainly an option. I'm looking for something a little bit more thought out (e.g. a hierarchical taxonomy with single inheritance).